# How To append in the XMl file using XMLWriter class

Tags: c#, xml

How To append in the XMl file using XMLWriter class

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlFragments = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlFragments.Indent = true ;
            XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter(_logFilePath, null);
            xWriter.WriteStartDocument();//starting document

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("values");//starting parent node
            xWriter.WriteStartElement("values1");//1st child node

            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", "200");//attributes of child node
            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("name", "ABCD");
            xWriter.WriteString("ISO Company");//innertext
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xWriter.WriteStartElement("num");//2nd child node
            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("more", "500");
            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("less", "101");
            xWriter.WriteString("numeric");
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xWriter.WriteStartElement("r", "runnnig", "");//3rd child node
            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("fast", "500km");
            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("slow", "10km");
            xWriter.WriteString("killometers");
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xWriter.WriteStartElement("character");
            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("char", "a");
            xWriter.WriteAttributeString("another", "b");
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();

            xWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            xWriter.Close();
```

I am trying to load xml file in xmlwriter but this class overwrite the previous tag but i dont want to overwrite the tag.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your XML format and indicate where you want to append contents?

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by XmlDocument.

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load("test.xml");
  XmlElement el = doc.CreateElement("child");
  el.InnerText = "This row is being appended to the end of the document.";
  doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(el);
  doc.Save("test.xml");
```

check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15278/How-to-Append-to-a-Large-XML-File) for more options.